# Block matrices where anti-diagonal elements are not trivial

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices

I have a matrix $$\mathbf{L} =\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{I}_{n \times n} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{n \times m} \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{m \times n} & \mathbf{I}_{m \times m}
\end{bmatrix}$$

where the diagonal blocks are identity matrices and anti-diagonal blocks are all $a$s. Is there a trick to find the eigenvalues and their multiplicities?

Numerically, I constantly get $0, 1, 2$ with multiplicities $1,m+n-2, 1$. I wonder if there exist methods that can get this solution analytically.

The context of the problem is that $\mathbf{L}$ is the graph Laplacian matrix of a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,m}$ where $$\mathbf{L} = \mathbf{I}-\mathbf{D}^{1/2}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{D}^{1/2}.$$

$\mathbf{D}$ is the diagonal degree matrix and $\mathbf{A}$ is the adjacency matrix.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What have you tried? What about when $(m, n) = (1, 1)$? Other small cases?

Comment: For a 2 by 2 matrix it could be easier to calculate eigenvalues using the determinants. However, I find it difficult to use this method if the matrix grows in the general case. In the original problem I had $a=1/\sqrt{mn}$ and I constantly get 0, 1, 2 as the eigenvalues (this might be important?) with 1 having multiplicity of $m + n -2$ using numerical methods. However I don't have clues how to find these values analytically.

Comment: This is all useful information and the the post should be edited to include this context and partial work on the problem.

Comment: @SammyBlack Yes thanks for the reminder. I will add that in.

Comment: I would suggest looking at small cases and working out the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda=0$ and $\lambda=2$—I'm guessing there's a pattern that can be proved. Then hopefully there's a pattern to the eigenspace for $\lambda=1$ that can also be proved somehow.

Comment: suggestion: consider $(L-I)$ instead.  This is real symmetric and rank 2 (and traceless).  What does $(L-I)^2$ look like?  It is block diagonal with easy spectra.  Then work backwards.